# Mathematica complement of a region

Tags: equation-solving, sets

I want to use Reduce Function to give me intersection of a region and complement of another region
The first region is:

```
c > 0 && d > (7 c)/3 && 
 (-3 c - d)/(4 c - 4 d) < λ < 1 && 
 ( c + d + c λ - d λ)/(1 + 2 λ) <= k < 1/2 (-c + d)
```

The second region which i want the complement is:

```
(-((2 c)/(c - d)) < λ <  1 && 
 (-2 c - c λ + d λ)/(2 λ) <= k < 1/2 (-c + d))
```

And here is the code I am using to take the intersection of the two regions is:

```
Reduce[(c > 0 && 
d > (7 c)/3 && (-3 c - d)/(4 c - 4 d) < λ < 1 && (
 c + d + c λ - d λ)/(1 + 2 λ) <= k < 
 1/2 (-c + d)) && (-((2 c)/(c - d)) < λ < 
 1 && (-2 c - c λ + d λ)/(2 λ) <= k < 
 1/2 (-c + d))]
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with the ouput that _Mathematica_ provides?

Comment: From the text, I guess you might want the of `cond1 = c > 0 && 
   d > (7 c)/3 && (-3 c - d)/(4 c - 4 d) < \[Lambda] < 
    1 && (c + d + c \[Lambda] - d \[Lambda])/(1 + 2 \[Lambda]) <= k < 
    1/2 (-c + d);
cond2 = (-((2 c)/(c - d)) < \[Lambda] < 
     1 && (-2 c - c \[Lambda] + d \[Lambda])/(2 \[Lambda]) <= k < 
     1/2 (-c + d));
Simplify[Reduce[cond1 && Not[cond2]]]`

Comment: What you are doing is sensible, but we can't really help you without knowing either what you want to do with the resulting region or what form you'd like it expressed in.  `CylindricalDecomposition` is a very useful tool for expressing inequalities in different forms.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. What I want to achieve is something which is in region 1 but not in region 2

Comment: Thank you very much Henrik, That is the answer